# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' Python Count Vectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to practice training a machine learning model to identify email spam but keep running into this error. Whenever I try and extract features using the bag of words method after having preprocessed the data it says

```
'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Here is my code for preprocessing the dataset:

```
def getDFcsv(fname):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    for w in range(len(df.Subject)): #index through each row of emailsubject
        #convert to lowercase
        sub = str(df['Subject'][w])
        cont = str(df['Text'][w])
        #remove punctuation
        sub = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', sub)
        cont = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', cont)
        #remove tags
        sub=re.sub("&lt;/?.*?&gt;"," &lt;&gt; ",sub)
        cont=re.sub("&lt;/?.*?&gt;"," &lt;&gt; ",cont)
        #remove digits and special chars
        sub = re.sub("(\\d|\\W)+"," ",sub)
        cont = re.sub("(\\d|\\W)+"," ",cont)
        #remove stopwords, get their base/stem representation, and convert to lower
        #Instantiate a stemmer object. Question: will this impact/ruin the word vector association?
        my_stemmer_object = SnowballStemmer("english") #stemming does this: running = run
        sub = [(my_stemmer_object.stem(i)).lower() for i in sub.split() if i not in stopwords.words('english') and len(i) >= 2]
        cont = [(my_stemmer_object.stem(i)).lower() for i in cont.split() if i not in stopwords.words('english') and len(i) >= 2]
        df['Subject'][w] = sub
        df['Text'][w] = cont

    return df
```

Here is my code for extracting features using bag of words:

```
def createBagOfWords(df):
    X_train_sms, X_test_sms, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['Text'], 
                                                    df['Type'], 
                                                    random_state=42)
    #test data distribution worked correctly
    #print('Number of rows in the total set: {}'.format(df.shape[0]))
    #print('Number of rows in the training set: {}'.format(y_train.shape[0]))
    #print('Number of rows in the test set: {}'.format(y_test.shape[0]))
    print(X_train_sms)
    # Instantiate the CountVectorizer method
    count_vector = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1), lowercase = True , stop_words =  'english')

    # Fit the training data and then return the matrix
    X_train = count_vector.fit_transform(X_train_sms)


    # Transform testing data and return the matrix. Note we are not fitting the testing data into the CountVectorizer()
    X_test = count_vector.transform(X_test_sms)

    #get a list of the words, or the column labels, that correspond to each word
    X_train_feature_list = count_vector.get_feature_names_out()

    #convert the training count vector to an array and then turn that array into a matrix
    doc_array =  X_train.toarray()
    frequency_matrix_X_train = pd.DataFrame((doc_array),columns = X_train_feature_list)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

I'm pretty sure my error is somewhere in the method handling preprocessing the dataset but I just don't know where.

Comment: You should update the 'Subject' and 'Text' columns directly in the DataFrame without converting them to lists.

Comment: What do you mean "*I don't know where*"? Please post the **full** error trace (which also tells you where) - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Error says `'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` - that means you're trying to call the lower () method on a `list` object and lists don't have that method.  lower is a string method.

These two lines:

```
    sub = [(my_stemmer_object.stem(i)).lower() for i in sub.split() if i not in stopwords.words('english') and len(i) >= 2]
    cont = [(my_stemmer_object.stem(i)).lower() for i in cont.split() if i not in stopwords.words('english') and len(i) >= 2]
```

look like the culprit.  What kind of object is `(my_stemmer_object.stem(i))`?  Apparently it's a list not a string, which is why you see that error.